# Книги для изучения Javascript

Tags: javascript

Посоветуйте пожалуйста хорошую(-ие) книгу(-и) по Javascript. Я новичок. Definitive Guide 6th Edition by David Flanagan как по-вашему мнению для новичка?
Заранее спасибо всем.

Comment: Девид Флэнаган не совсем для новичка, но в принципе реален для освоения и охватывает практически весь язык и его взаимодействие с браузером. Это была моя первая книга по JS и вторая по счету после изучения ActionScript (который потом внезапно загнулся).

Answer (score -1):

https://eloquentjavascript.net/

Отличная книга! Есть перевод на русский язык, но последне самое свежее издание только на английском. Рекомендую читать именно его. Книга бесплатна, и сопровождается заданиями, которые можно сделать прямо в на сайте в песочнице.

Comment: Да я пользуюсь этой книгой, она удобна только как электронная версия. А я хочу купить книжную версию Definitive Guide с Амазона, но просто не знаю это хороший выбор или нет, тем более книга будет на английском языке, поэтому еще сложнее будет получить информацию. Ибо нет в продаже русской версии. @Roman Andreev

Comment: @Afina eloquent javascript так же можно купить на амазоне в виде бумажной книги. Еще You Don't Know JS  можете посмотреть(но она так же официально есть в бесплатном доступе он-лайн)

Comment: Да я знаю эти книги тоже, просто не знаю какую именно выбрать. Какой выбор будет оптимальным? @Roman Andreev

Comment: оптимально - прочитать все :)